# Como filtro los documentos de un array que cumplan una condicion - Mongoose

Tags: array, nodejs, mongodb, moongose, aggregate

Tengo una coleccion (servicebyAff) en MongoDB con la siguiente estructura en sus documentos:

```
 {
    "category": [
        {
            "active": true,
            "enabled": true,
            "service": [
                "5ce520370fc47e2d0edc4411"
            ],
            "menu": [],
            "_id": "5dd3576a222f4f265d3657ce",
            "name": {
                "en": "ACTH",
                "es": "ACTH"
            },
            "description": {
                "en": "ACTH",
                "es": "ACTH"
            },
            "parentCategory": [
                "5dd096dd60c43279e76e8d08"
            ],
            "updatedBy": "5cd51f9c33d554e479daaee8",
            "createdAt": "2019-11-19T02:46:02.080Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-11-19T02:46:02.080Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "active": true,
            "enabled": true,
            "service": [
                "5ce520370fc47e2d0edc4411"
            ],
            "menu": [],
            "_id": "5dd35d02222f4f265d3657e3",
            "name": {
                "en": "ANA",
                "es": "ANA"
            },
            "description": {
                "en": "ANA",
                "es": "ANA"
            },
            "parentCategory": [
                "5dd0971260c43279e76e8d09"
            ],
            "updatedBy": "5cd51f9c33d554e479daaee8",
            "createdAt": "2019-11-19T03:09:54.050Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-11-19T03:09:54.050Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "subCategory": [],
    "appointmentRequired": false,
    "enabled": true,
    "atHome": true,
    "_id": "6287b77d35a7804b30e47d16",
    "affiliate": "61097293913cf4eaacb177b2",
    "officePhone": "+50433333333",
    "place": {
        "loc": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -88.0264096,
                15.5085874
            ]
        },
        "enabled": true,
        "virtual": false,
        "_id": "6109766f913cf469f6b177ba",
        "country": "HND",
        "countryName": "Honduras",
        "city": "San Pedro Sula 21102",
        "name": "Laboratorios CDC",
        "createdBy": "5cd51f9c33d554e479daaee8",
        "address": "6ta avenida 4ta calle N.O San Pedro Sula Cortes HN, 4 Calle NO, Barrio Guamilito, San Pedro Sula 21102, Sector 1 Nor-Oeste, San Pedro Sula, San Pedro Sula, Cortés Department, Honduras, GX5F+CC San Pedro Sula",
        "createdAt": "2021-08-03T17:01:35.775Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-08-03T17:01:35.775Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "room": "Laboratorios CDC, Plaza Bulevares",
    "floor": 23,
    "coverageRadiusInKm": 3,
    "service": {
        "active": true,
        "enabled": true,
        "affiliateType": [
            "5d242feb3555ec2b76e86bce",
            "5d242fc13555ec2b76e86bcd"
        ],
        "isAppointment": false,
        "showIsAppointment": false,
        "isVirtual": false,
        "atHome": true,
        "onPlace": false,
        "_id": "5ce520370fc47e2d0edc4411",
        "name": {
            "en": "Laboratory Tests At Home",
            "es": "Análisis de Laboratorio Domicilio"
        },
        "description": {
            "en": "Laboratory Tests At Home",
            "es": "Análisis de Laboratorio A Domicilio"
        },
        "createdAt": "2019-05-22T10:11:03.945Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-09-30T20:58:57.714Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "price": 0,
    "createdAt": "2022-05-20T15:45:01.728Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-05-20T23:33:59.947Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Como se puede observar dentro del arreglo "category" que pertenece a una coleccion llamada categories, viene un atributo llamado "parentCategory" el cual es un arreglo de Ids, estos Ids son documentos dentro de la coleccion categories. Es decir dentro de parentCategory se esta mandando a llamar Ids que estan dentro de la misma colección

¿Qué es lo que yo busco?

Que en lugar de que me traiga el arreglo tipo:

```
 "parentCategory": [
                "5dd096dd60c43279e76e8d08"
            ]
```

Vaya y busque en categories el Id, lo filtre y me lo agrupe en dentro de parentCategory algo asi:

```
    "parentCategory": [
        {
            "id": "5dd096dd60c43279e76e8d08",
            "active": true,
            "enabled": true,
            "service": [],
            "menu": [],
            "name": {},
            "description": {},
            "updatedBy": "5cd51f9c33d554e479daaee8",
            "createdAt": "2019-11-17T00: 39: 57.807+00: 00",
            "updatedAt": "2020-02-24T16: 36: 40.935+00: 00",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
```

Por el momento llevo algo asi:

```js
export const categoriesAtHome = async(req: Request & any, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    // ?=idService="xxx"&idCategories=""&enable=true
    //        {$or: [{service: {ObjectId('5ce520370fc47e2d0edc4411')}}], enabled: true}
    const {
      affiliateId
    } = req.params;
    const affiliateObjectId = Types.ObjectId(affiliateId);

    // const sort: any = { "createdAt": -1 };

    // const categoriesByAtHome = await Category.find({
    //     service: idServiceObjectId,
    //     enabled: true,
    // }).populate("service").populate("subCategory").populate("menu").sort(sort).lean().exec();

    const categoryConditions = {
      enabled: true,
      active: true
    };

    let data = await ServicesByAffiliate.aggregate([{
        $match: {
          affiliate: affiliateObjectId,
          enabled: true
        }
      }, {
        $lookup: {
          from: "services",
          localField: "service",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "service"
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$service"
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "categories",
          localField: "category",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "category"
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          opened: "$category.parentCategory"
        }
      }
      // {
      //     $graphLookup: {
      //         restrictSearchWithMatch: categoryConditions,
      //         from: "categories",
      //         startWith: "$_id",
      //         connectFromField: "_id",
      //         connectToField: "parentCategory",
      //         depthField: "depth",
      //         as: "items"
      //     }
      // }
    ])

    res.status(200).json({
      data: data
    });


  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      error: true,
      message: error.toString()
    });
  }

};
```

¿Alguien podría ayudarme porfavor? Voy a poner en recompensa en tres dias esta pregunta

Estoy trabajando con Nodejs y Moogose

Comment: Por favor, no [dupliques](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/537494/cual-es-la-mejor-forma-de-filtrar-objetos-de-grandes-cantidades) preguntas. En todo caso, elimina una de las 2. La anterior la he votado para reapertura gracias a la edición que has realizado sobre la misma. Toma una decisión y elimina una de las 2 preguntas. Saludos

Comment: La lista de `parentCategory` es de tipo `string`?

Comment: Si, es un string. Es un arreglo de strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que estás tratando de hacer un [`$lookup`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) usando como referencia valores de diferente tipo.

La lista de `parentCategory` es de tipo cadena (`string`) y estás intentando compararla con valores de tipo [`ObjectId`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/). Es por ello que te devuelve una lista vacía donde debería devolver una lista con los documentos `parentCategory` que intentas obtener.

Puedes ver el siguiente [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e_UY7SSHKMH) como ejemplo.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es simple, debes convertir los valores de tipo cadena en valores de tipo ObjectId para cada elemento de la lista de `parentCategory`, de esta forma la etapa `$lookup` devolverá la lista con la información requerida.

Para convertir los valores de la lista en ObjectId's usaremos una etapa [`$addFields`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) junto con el operador de agregación [`$map`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), que como su nombre indica realiza un "mapeo" de los elementos existentes en una lista devolviendo una versión de los mismos a los que se les ha aplicado alguna operación. La operación que aplicaremos sobre cada elemento será convertirlo en ObjectId usando el operador de conversión [`$toObjectId`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/).

La etapa `$addFields` usando `$map` y `$toObjectId` podría verse así:

```js
{
  $addFields: {
    parentCategory: {
      $map: {
        input: "$parentCategory",
        as: "parent",
        in: {
          $toObjectId: "$$parent"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hay que notar el uso de la expresión `"$$parent"`, que es un [variable de agregación](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) de MongoDB. En este caso se usa para referirse a la variable `parent` declarada en el campo `as` del operador `$map`.

Dependiendo de cómo tengas armada toda tu agregación, esta sería la forma de convertir cada elemento de `parentCategory` en un ObjectId para que luego puedas usarlo en una etapa `$lookup`. Puedes ver el siguiente [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/URqHJVr_19Z) como ejemplo.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Hola! Muchqas gracias por tu amplia explicación, la necesitaba porque normalmente estoy acostumbrada a que practicamente mongo me lo de todo, pero trabajar en este query me sirvio para ver ciertas cosas que antes no sabía. Sabes, que tambien estuve haciendo diferentes pruebas y tambien me salio con un $addField. Lo probe agregando un $lookup para "parentCategory" al final del query y se puede usar $firstoperator en lugar de $unwind  en $addFields